# In perl, how to read from STDIN until we enounter a space or a newline?

Tags: perl, stdin

In perl, I'm only familiar with using the usual

```
chomp(my $ip = <>);
```

If this $ip is "words separated by space", I'd have to use split to get "words", "separated", "by" and "space".

Is there a way to read word by word in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the input record separator `$/` to space will read "word by word". You may find the results counter-intuitive, so *be careful what you wish for*.

Try for example:

```
perl -nwe 'BEGIN { $/ = " ";} print "Line: $_"'
```

It will read from stdin, and print it back to you, but one word at the time. However, as you shall notice, newline (pressing ENTER) is still quite an integral part of the process.

`$/` cannot be smart, however. It's just the character(s) we use to tell input records apart, and it does affect a good many other things besides STDIN, so using it will most likely confuse you. Unless, of course, you use it locally, and only exactly where you want it.

```
{  # make this part lexically scoped
    local $/ = " ";  # use local version of $/
    while (<>) {
        chomp(my $ip = $_);  # note that chomp removes space instead
    }
}  # End of scope, $/ is back to normal
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change the input record separator `$/` to space. (I don't recommend doing this, read to the end)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

open(my $in, "<", "data.txt") or die "can't open input: $!";
local $/ = " ";
while(<$in>) {
    chomp;
    print "\'$_\'\n";
}
```

In that case, the input gets separated by spaces *but not newlines*. Similarly, chomp uses the value of the record separator, so this gives you (for multiple lines):

- Word ending a line is not separated from the one starting the next line. You can workaround that by ending lines with a space, but that's awkward.
- You still need to get rid of the newline character, which won't be removed by chomp.

So in the end, if you have more then one line, you'll usually be better of with keeping the default record separator and splitting the lines to words.

Comment: Note: You really should make it a habit to always `use warnings`. You don't have to escape single quote `'` inside a double quoted string (and vice versa). Also, using `local` this way has no practical use, since the scope of this local variable will be global anyway.

Comment: local makes it local for the file, which is exactly what was intended. But enclosing it in a block is a better practice, I agree

Comment: File scoping only makes sense if there is more than one file.